# Python TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'> when using math.floor() for iloc index lookup value

Tags: python, dataframe, math, floor

I'm having an issue where I need a function to find a corresponding value from within a dataframe with multiple rows within them, looking similar to:

```
       Value
0      1.2332165631653
1      6.5651324661235
2      2.3651432415454
3      1.6566584651432
4      9.5168743514354
5 ...
```

My function looks like this:

```
import math
import dataframe as df
df1 = df.read_csv('Data1.csv')
df2 = df.read_csv('Data2.csv')

def dfFunction (A, B):
    Step = 10
    AB = A * B
    ABInt = math.floor(AB / Step)
    dfValue = df1.iloc[ABInt]
    return AB / dfValue
```

When I input A and B values as int or float, the function works, but when I try to apply the function to df2 (similar to df1 in terms of layout, just additional columns of floats), I'm returning this error.

I've tried `df2.apply(dfFunction(df2.ColumnA, df2.ColumnB), axis = 1)` and simply `dfFunction(df2.ColumnA, df2.ColumnB)`.

I fundamentally understand the error, since it's highlighting the `math.floor()` line, but I can't use a float to look up the row index of df1 with a float. Is there another way I can have the function or looking up the data value? I'd just use iloc() if the floats weren't massive decimal places, but the values are means from another portion of the code.

Please let me know if further clarification is needed; I'm only a beginning with Python and Stack :)

Comment: To me, this implies that some of your columns are not numeric.  Do you have objects or strings in some of them?

Comment: There is possibly NaN in there; I'll see what happens if I filter them out

Comment: Nope. Still get presented with the same error. I checked with .info() and all the data within ColumnA and ColumnB are floats